# Texturing when Breaking objects?

Tags: texturing

I have a issue which I am not sure how to fix, I downloaded the JaggedCliff material from Poliigon to test a falling rock which breaks into smaller parts upon impact.

The problem is that the smaller parts are not textured correctly and all the texture appears stretched and all sorts on most of them.

I used the Cell Fracture addon to break a standard sphere into pieces.

I am thinking that do i need to go through each stone and try to unwrap the texture so it looks good on every piece one by one ? or is there an easier way to do this?

[Small update, I watched a CG Geek tutorial from 4 years ago showing how to smash through a wall but the issue I see with his method is that the fractures are not uniformed or would I need to use a plane projecting the texture for every possible rotation?

Thanks!

[image: Broken Textures]